# How to split input matrix to sub-matrixes for parallel GPU processing?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am new on stackoverflow and I am glad to post my first question. I am actually new in the world of programming but I have some basic knowledge anyway, I am actually using Python to solve a classification problem. I have a big set of data (in my actual problem n=60326) and each vector has about 416 dimension. I need to calculate the manhattan distance between these different vectors in order to classify my dataset based on similarity (take a random reference vector and merge closest vectors to it where distance range between 0 and 1) I am already familiar with Kmeans and basic ML clustering algorithms...My actual problem is that I need to accelerate time using GPU (CUDA) to initially calculate the matrix of distances before starting the classification, which has a size of n² (60326 x 60326, we can reduce it to n²/2 because it is a symmetric matrix) So my actual problem is how to implement CUDA in this case, I have already installed the CUDA package with ANACONDA.

I started with parallel CPU's processing and it provided a memory error

```
import pandas as pd
import time  
import time
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
signatures=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\YMH1\\Documents\\Reduce Java code\\BOBST.txt", sep=' ',header=None,usecols=[*range(2,417)])
PartName = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\YMH1\\Documents\\Reduce Java code\\misumi_new.txt', sep=' ', header=None, usecols=[*range(0,1)])
signatures_vector=np.array(signatures)
PartName_vector=np.array(PartName)
D = pairwise_distances(X = signatures_vector, metric = 'manhattan', n_jobs = -1)
print(D)
```

Now, I am trying to implement CUDA since it speeds up time, so I coded this:

```
from __future__ import division
from numba import cuda, float32
import pandas as pd
import math
signatures=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\YMH1\\Documents\\Reduce Java code\\BOBST.txt", sep=';',header=None,usecols=[*range(2,418)])
signatures_vector=np.array(signatures)
@cuda.jit
def manhattan(an_array):
  x, y = cuda.grid(2)
  "Here we define the Manhattan distance"
  return an_array
data=signatures_vector
threadsperblock = (16, 16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(data.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(data.shape[1] / threadsperblock[1])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)
manhattan[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](data)
print(data)
```

My question is how to define the manhattan norm when we use CUDA, what are the modifications to be made inside the def manhattan
And thank you very much

Comment: It is difficult to get an answer to such a broad question. Start with Anaconda CUDA tutorials and see if you can implement something.

Comment: more specifically, I need to know how to make sub-matrixes from the original input matrix, send them to the GPU and then at the end concatenate the results to get the final results

Comment: Then update the post and the title accordingly to increase your chances of getting a good answer to those questions. The more specific your question is, the more are your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Can you write the ordinary python code to do what you want in a succinct fashion?  If so, showing that to others might help the quality of your post a bit.  Even that sort of question ("show me how to do this in CUDA") is frowned on, if you haven't made an attempt and don't show what you've done so far and what specifically is not working.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I didn't post my problem in a comprehensible way....It's my first post here..I will make some modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how to define the manhattan norm when we use CUDA, what are the modifications to be made inside the def manhattan

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html), the `manhattan` distance metric is the summation between two vectors of the absolute values of the elementwise differences.

One problem you are likely running into is one of memory space.  If we assume that the output of the distance metric (i.e. the matrix elements) is expressed as an ordinary python quantity, this will probably occupy 8 bytes of memory. For the stated dimension (60326), this means the matrix would occupy 60326*60326*8 bytes, which is almost 30GB.  Even if we assume that you are only storing half of that, and even if we assume a 32-bit sum of absolute differences, this will still be over 7GB of storage needed.

When I tried to run such a test using the sckit-learn method, I had trouble, even on a machine that had 128GB of system memory:

```
# cat t5.py
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.spatial import distance
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

vector_length = 416
num_signatures = 60000
sig_pattern = np.array([0,1,2,3], dtype=np.float32).reshape(4,1)
signatures = np.tile(sig_pattern,(num_signatures, vector_length//sig_pattern.shape[1]))
E = pairwise_distances(signatures, metric = 'manhattan', n_jobs = -1)
print(E[:8,:8])
# time python t5.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t5.py", line 17, in <module>
    E = pairwise_distances(signatures, metric = 'manhattan', n_jobs = -1)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1247, in pairwise_distances
    return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1096, in _parallel_pairwise
    for s in gen_even_slices(Y.shape[0], n_jobs))
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 789, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 699, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 572, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result:
'[array([[ 0.,  416.,  832., ...,  416.,  832., 1248.],
       [ 416.,    0.,  416., ...,    0.,  416.,  832.],
       [ 832.,  416.,    0., ...,  416.,    0.,  416.],
       ...,
       [ 416.,    0.,  416., ...,    0.,  416.,  832.],
       [ 832.,  416.,    0., ...,  416.,    0.,  416.],
       [1248.,  832.,  416., ...,  832.,  416.,    0.]])]'. Reason: 'OverflowError('cannot serialize a string larger than 2 GiB',)'

real    31m47.361s
user    405m28.155s
sys     8m19.851s
```

In that situation, it appeared to take about 30 minutes to compute on my machine.  The output test matrix appeared approximately correct, but an error was thrown by python because some intermediate representation was >2GB.

The memory size issue will be one of the important problems to think about in a numba/cuda realization as well.

The operation to be performed is relatively simple, however.  And according to my testing, it can run significantly quicker than the numpy/scikit-learn method.

Here is a worked example:

```
# cat t4.py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from numba import cuda,float32

vector_length = 416
num_vecs_per_block = 8
sm_size = vector_length*num_vecs_per_block
#num_sig must be divisible by num_vecs_per_block
@cuda.jit('void(float32[:,:], float32[:,:], int32, int32)')
def manhattan(signatures, distances, num_sig, vec_len):
    sm = cuda.shared.array(sm_size, float32)
    temp = cuda.local.array(num_vecs_per_block, dtype = float32)
    bid = cuda.blockIdx.x
    tid = cuda.threadIdx.x
    bdim = cuda.blockDim.x
# load shared memory with vectors for comparison
    if tid < num_vecs_per_block:
        for i in range(vec_len):
            sm[i*num_vecs_per_block+tid] = signatures[i, bid*num_vecs_per_block+tid];
    cuda.syncthreads()
#block-stride loop through the vector array
# the addition below to tid results in only elements above the diagonal being computed
# since the output matrix is symmetric
    svec = tid +(bid*num_vecs_per_block)
    while svec < num_sig:
        for i in range(num_vecs_per_block):
            temp[i] = 0
        for i in range(vec_len):
            src = signatures[i,svec]
            for j in range(num_vecs_per_block):
                #elementwise difference
                sdist = src - sm[i*num_vecs_per_block + j]
                #absolute value
                if sdist < 0:
                    sdist *= -1
                #sum
                temp[j] += sdist
        for i in range(num_vecs_per_block):
            distances[bid*num_vecs_per_block+i, svec] = temp[i]
        svec += bdim

num_signatures = 60000
sig_pattern = np.array([0,1,2,3], dtype=np.float32)
signatures = np.tile(sig_pattern,(num_signatures//sig_pattern.shape[0], vector_length))
distances  = np.zeros((num_signatures, num_signatures), dtype=np.float32)
threadsperblock = 1024
blockspergrid   = num_signatures//num_vecs_per_block
d_signatures = cuda.to_device(signatures)
d_distances = cuda.device_array_like(distances)
manhattan[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_signatures, d_distances, num_signatures, vector_length)
d_distances.copy_to_host(distances)
print(distances[:16,:16])
# time python t4.py
[[   0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.]
 [ 416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.]
 [ 832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.]
 [1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0.]
 [   0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.]
 [ 416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.]
 [ 832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.]
 [1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  416.  832. 1248.    0.  416.  832. 1248.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  832.  416.    0.  416.  832.  416.    0.  416.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0. 1248.  832.  416.    0.]]

real    0m11.580s
user    0m5.579s
sys     0m5.922s
#
```

In this case, I have limited the `signatures` vectors to 60000 total, instead of 60320, because the larger number resulted in a output matrix that was too large to fit in the available memory of my 16GB Tesla P100 GPU.  **If your GPU has less than 16GB of memory, this code won't work as-is.**  You would need to scale the problem down to a smaller number of signature vectors.  It should be relatively straightforward to partition the vectors in two two groups, and perform distance calculations between the two groups, to fill out the entire matrix.

However the numba code on my test machine runs in about 11 seconds, and seems to produce an equivalent result for the very small 16x16 piece of the output matrix that I am printing out.

If I profile this code, I actually discover that the GPU kernel is running in about 3 seconds, the data transfer time of the huge output matrix from GPU to CPU is taking about 6 seconds, and the remainder is about 2 seconds of python overhead.

The actual GPU algorithm is block oriented.  Each block is responsible for comparison of 8 vectors against the entire vector array.  Each block starts by loading 8 vectors into shared memory, and then traverses the entire vector array, computing the manhattan distance against each of these 8 vectors.  The block uses a block-stride loop to run through the entire array.  At the end of each loop iteration, the 8 manhattan distances corresponding to the current comparison are written to the output array.

In addition there is a subtle change to the code, so that only the matrix output values above the diagonal are computed.  Since computation is done block-wise, blocks that have no elements above the diagonal are not computed.  This cuts processing time approximately in half, but the full output matrix is still in memory.  For this reason, the lower-left quadrant of my 16x16 output above is all zero, because the 8x8 quadrant is entirely "below" the diagonal, so the processing for it is skipped, due to the similarity situation already pointed out in the question.